# Why when setting the order of scripts executing still one script is executing first?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts attached to the same emptygameobject.
The first script is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int numberOfObjects;
    public GameObject objectToPlace;
    public Vector3 newObjectsSize = new Vector3(5, 5, 5);
    public float spawnSpeed = 0.1f;

    private int wallsLengthX;
    private int wallsLengthZ;
    private int wallsPosX;
    private int wallsPosZ;
    private int currentObjects;
    private List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();

    void Start()
    {
        var wi = GetComponent<Walls>();
        wallsLengthX = (int)wi.lengthX;
        wallsLengthZ = (int)wi.lengthZ;
        wallsPosX = (int)wi.wallsStartPosition.x;
        wallsPosZ = (int)wi.wallsStartPosition.z;

        StartCoroutine(Spawn());
    }

    IEnumerator Spawn()
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            GameObject newObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(objectToPlace);
            newObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(newObjectsSize.x, newObjectsSize.y, newObjectsSize.z);
            newObject.transform.localPosition = GenerateRandomPositions(newObject);
            newObject.name = "Spawned Object";
            newObject.tag = "Spawned Object";
            objects.Add(newObject);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnSpeed);
            currentObjects += 1;
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GenerateRandomPositions(GameObject newObject)
    {
        float paddingX = Mathf.Clamp(newObject.transform.localScale.x, 0, wallsLengthX) / 2f;
        float paddingZ = Mathf.Clamp(newObject.transform.localScale.z, 0, wallsLengthZ) / 2f;
        float originX = wallsPosX + paddingX - wallsLengthX / 2f;
        float originZ = wallsPosZ + paddingZ - wallsLengthZ / 2f;
        float posx = UnityEngine.Random.Range(originX, originX + wallsLengthX - paddingX);
        float posz = UnityEngine.Random.Range(originZ, originZ + wallsLengthZ - paddingZ);
        float posy = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(posx, 0, posz));

        return new Vector3(posx, posy, posz);
    }
}
```

The second script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WayPoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    public Transform target;
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public float moveSpeed1 = 10f;
    public float slowDownSpeed = 3f;
    public float reverseSlowDownSpeed = 3f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1f;

    private Transform myTransform;
    private int targetsIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 originalPosition;
    private GameObject[] robots;

    public Transform reverseTarget;
    private int reverseTargetsIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 reverseOriginalPosition;

    public bool random = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        myTransform = transform;
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Spawned Object");
```

The first script spawn new 10 cubes.
But the second script waypoints variable is getting only 1 "Spawned Object" and not 10.

When i used a break point i see that it's executing the first script doing in the loop once:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
```

But then it's jumping to the second script getting one "Spawned Object" and then back to the first script and make the rest of the loop.

And what i want is that it will make first the whole loop spawn 10 cubes thne to get them all with the second script.

I even did in the editor: Edit > Project Settings > Script Execution Order
But still it's not doing first the whole loop only one iterate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a yield in `Spawn()` coroutine:

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnSpeed);
```

The `Start()` functions are being called in the correct order but the first script is just starting a coroutine that yields after each iteration.  After the first yield, it's going to wait to continue until that `WaitForSeconds` ends; in the mean-time, the second script will run its `Start()`.

As a solution, you aren't going to be able to fix this with script execution order.  Your second script will have to wait until the first script is done running its `Spawn()` coroutine. There are plenty of ways to do this but the easiest would be to either expose the `Coroutine` object returned by `StartCoroutine()` or make something like a `bool DoneSpawning` flag in your `SpawnObjects` class.